# Existence of extreme point $x^*$ of $B_{E^*}$ 'closed' to $y^*$ that norms at $u$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space.

> *Question:* For any $\varepsilon>0, u\in E$ and $y^*\in\text{ext}\left( B_{E^*} \right)$ such that $|y^*(u) - \|u\|| < \varepsilon,$ does there exist $x^*\in E^*$ such that
>
> $(1)$ $x^*\in\text{ext}\left( B_{E^*} \right),$
>
> $(2)$ $x^*(u) = \|u\|,$
>
> $(3)$ $\|y^*-x^*\|_{op}<\varepsilon?$

By defining the set
$$\{x^*\in E^*: \|x^*\|\leq 1, x^*(u)=\|u\|\},$$
one can show existence of $x^*$ that satisfies the $(1)$ and $(2),$ but may not satisfy $(3)$ (a proof involves Hahn-Banach to ensure the set is nonempty, Banach-Alaoglu to ensures that the set is compact in weak$^*$ topology and lastly, Krein-Milman to obtain extreme point).
However, if we define
$$\{x^*\in E^*: \|x^*\|\leq 1, x^*(u)=\|u\|, \|y^*-x^*\|_{op}<\varepsilon\},$$
I am not able to prove that the set is nonempty.

---

*Notations:* Let $E$ be a Banach space. Denote $E^*$ to be its dual space, that is, a space containing bounded linear functionals on $E.$
Let $B_{E^*}$ be the closed unit ball of $E^*.$
We say that $x^*$ is an extreme point of $B_{E^*}$ if it cannot be expressed as midpoint of two elements from $B_{E^*}.$

For any $x^*\in E^*,$ its operator norm is defined by
$$\|x^*\|_{op} = \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}|x^*(x)|.$$

Comment: Well, if $\|y^\ast - x^\ast\|_{op}$ is small, and $x^\ast (u) = \|u\|$, then necessarily $y^\ast(u)$ is close to $\|u\|$ (how close?). So if this necessary condition is not satisfied, you won't be able to find $x^\ast$ as you want.

Comment: @PhoemueX I have added the necessity $y^*(u)$ is closed $\|u\|$ in my question.